# How to bypass 403 response code in python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, data-mining, data-extraction

I am having trouble in getting 200 response from website. When I send request to this url https://www.saturn.de/de/category/_business-notebooks-581039.html it return 403 response code in python

here is my code.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.saturn.de/de/category/_business-notebooks-581039.html'

headers = {
    
    'User-Agent':'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.status_code
403
```

please anyone can guide me how I can get 200 response from this website.

Comment: I tried your code and got a warning message saying that the request was "too fast" (zu schnell). The website uses some anti-scrapping protection so I guess you will have to try to a find workaround on your own.

Comment: Cloudflare bot protection is enabled on that website, which is why your requests are failing. You can tell this by the cookies on the page:

`__cf_bm` = Cloudflare Bot Management